# Does BackInt support for Sybase Backup?

Tags: sybase, database-backups, sap-ase

BackInt agent was natively integrated with SAP systems and supports backup of SAP HANA database. Does BackInt supports for Backup of Sybase(ASE) database instances as well?

Didn't find enough information whether BackInt agent supports backup support for Sybase databases or not?